# Как изменить фоновый цвет главной формы?

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю приложение, и не получается изменить фоновый цвет главной формы, в чем проблема?
При выборе параметра в comboBoxBackgroundСolor должен меняться BackColor у FormMain.

Код:

```
public partial class FormHelp : Form
    {

        public FormHelp()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboBoxBackgroundColor.Items.Add("Белый" + Environment.NewLine);
            comboBoxBackgroundColor.Items.Add("Черный" + Environment.NewLine);
        }

        private void comboBoxBackgroundColor_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormMain f1 = new FormMain();
            switch (comboBoxBackgroundColor.SelectedIndex)
            {
                case 0: f1.BackColor = SystemColors.Control; break;
                case 1: f1.BackColor = SystemColors.Desktop; break;
            }

        }
    }
```

Скриншоты форм:

[image: скрины форм]

Comment: Станданртная ошибка начинающих: вы создаёте _новый_ экземпляр формы и меняете свойство у него. А надо передавать ссылку на _существующий_ экземпляр формы.